# Are there any coding standards available for spring or springMVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Are there any coding standards available for spring or springMVC.

Comment: What do you expect to find in those coding standards that is not covered in Java code conventions?

Comment: Hi JB, I want to know if there is any code review checklist or best practices avaialble

Comment: Yes, there is: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Code-Style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge there are no such standards.  But there are couple of class-level annotations for describing the role of a particular bean for example

@Component, @Repository, @Service, @Controller.